# How to use node sqlite3 with q (promise)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, promise

I'm trying to use the promise with sqlite3. Here is a part of my source code:

```js
this.deleteTag = function(tag, project){
    var db = this.db;
    if (project){
        return q.nfcall(db.run, "DELETE FROM tag2project WHERE tag = ? AND project = ?",
            [tag.id, project.id]);
    }else{
        return q.all([
            q.nfcall(db.run, "DELETE FROM tag2project WHERE tag = ?", [tag.id]),
            q.nfcall(db.run, "DELETE FROM tags WHERE id = ?", [tag.id])
        ]);
    }
};
```

But those promises only enter in .fail where error is:

```js
[TypeError: Database object expected]
```

Searching for this error only got me to the sourcecode of sqlite itself https://github.com/joyent/smartos-live/blob/master/src/node-sqlite3/src/statement.cc#L91

The old version using simple callback is working so there is not error in this.db or the sql query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think db.run is not function but method. from Q doc:

> If you are working with methods, instead of simple functions, you can
>   easily run in to the usual problems where passing a method to another
>   function—like Q.nfcall—"un-binds" the method from its owner. To avoid
>   this, you can either use Function.prototype.bind or  some nice
>   shortcut methods we provide:
>
> ```
> return Q.ninvoke(redisClient, "get", "user:1:id");
> return Q.npost(redisClient, "get", ["user:1:id"]);
> ```

But I always use Q.denodeify or Q.nbind. it is cleaner.

> You can also create reusable wrappers with Q.denodeify or Q.nbind:
>
> ```
> var readFile = Q.denodeify(FS.readFile);
> return readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8");
>
> var redisClientGet = Q.nbind(redisClient.get, redisClient);
> return redisClientGet("user:1:id");
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the object that you created when you promisify the function.

Example

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');
const db = new lib_sqlite3.Database(_dirname + '/your-db-path');

const runAsync = promisify(db.run.bind(db));
```