# Turn from promise into async

Tags: javascript

I am making a project with electron and SQLite and I came across a problem with synchronicity.
after searching I came up with the following solution but I wonder If I can turn the following promises into async/await pattern

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./test.db', (err) => {
    if (err) console.error('error with database ', err);
});

console.log('start');

function getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.get('select * from TYPE', (err, row) => {
            if (!err) resolve(row);
        });
    });
}

async function play() {
    var a;
    a = await getData();
    console.log(a);
}

play();
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with  `async.js`? There is no trace of this library in your code...

Comment: _" I wonder If I can turn the following promises into async/await pattern"_ No, you can't. There is a promisified version of SQLite for Node.js and there are ways to promisify this functions but simple `utils.promisify` doesn't work here.

Comment: This comment has nothing to do with the question, but you should probably call `reject()` if the `db.get()` result contains an error. `db.get('query', (err, row) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(row))`

Comment: this is just an example in order to clarify my question, I am not including this code in my project

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are already (correctly) using the async/await pattern. There is nothing to change here.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I meant do something like `a = await db.get("select * from type",[])` but this return `Database {}`

Comment: Does `db.get()` return a Promise? Looks like it does -- but the data you're looking for is returned in the callback. You must wrap it in a promise if you wish to use it like one.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev _"You must wrap it in a promise if you wish to use it like one"_ But you don't have to do it by hand. That's the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [`sqlite3-promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3-promisify):

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3-promisify').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./test.db', (err) => {
    if (err) console.error('error with database ', err);
});

console.log('start');

async function getData() {
    return await db.get('select * from TYPE');
}

async function play() {
    var a;
    a = await getData();
    console.log(a);
}

play();
```

or [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54789239/4645334) yourself:

```
const util = require ('util');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./test.db', (err) => {
    if (err) console.error('error with database ', err);
});

console.log('start');

async function getData() {
    return await util.promisify(db.get.bind(db))('select * from TYPE');
}

async function play() {
    var a;
    a = await getData();
    console.log(a);
}

play();
```

Comment: utils does not have promisify function otherwise util does.
your solution has worked but according to sqlite3 docs they said the package support assynchronicity

Comment: @MURHAFAL-MSRI I worked with SQLite3 in a project some weeks ago and I had the same question. I found these two ways to solve it and I chose the latter. I didn't find a way without promisify and the existence of the package `sqlite3-promisify` indicates that there is no way. Asynchronicity doesn't necessarily mean it works with promises and async/await. It can work asynchronously with callbacks.